# How do you get the post thumbnail size?

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I know how to *set* the size of a post thumbnail image using the WP Admin [Media Settings](https://en.support.wordpress.com/settings/media-settings/) or using [this function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size):

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 )
```

But how would one get the image **width** *and* **height** that have been set for an image thumbnail size?

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
get_post_thumbnail_size(); // return array(150, 150)
```

How would this be done? Is it by using `get_option()`, and would the options keys be for thumbnail width and height?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When an image size is added either by WordPress(`add_image_size`), or by a plugin or your own custom code it gets added into the `$_wp_additional_image_sizes` global, i can't find a similar function for pulling data from that global, but you could certainly just look inside the global to determine what width and height a registered image size has.

**Example:**

```
global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
// Output width
echo $_wp_additional_image_sizes['post_thumbnail']['width'];
// Output height
echo $_wp_additional_image_sizes['post_thumbnail']['height'];
```

Of course just be sure to reference those values at a point after you've set the size. So if for example you're setting the thumbnail size during init, you'll need to make sure to do whatever you need to after that point(else you'll get back the sizes as they were prior to setting them).

Hope that helps.

Comment: It appears to be `post-thumbnail` rather than `post_thubmnail` (WP3.6)

Answer (score 15):

There is however another way:

```
get_option( 'thumbnail_size_w' );
get_option( 'thumbnail_size_h' );
```

<sup>Note: `thumbnail` is one of the sizes set inside `$_wp_additional_image_sizes`. So the call to `get_option()` will work for every other image size too.</sup>

Comment: This is actually the best option because plugin can run their hooks on it.

Comment: That's why I am surprised it hasn't been mentioned yet.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for custom image sizes?

Answer (score 6):

The only thing still missing is the thumbnail's ID:

```
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
$attachment = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id );
$width=$attachment[1];
$height=$attachment[2];
```

Comment: Actually this is the only really useful answer for all possible cases, especially when not in post's context.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to why it's such a pain to retrieve these numbers, a core enchancement that contains a finished patch. Sadly it's still not in core.

Just follow the progress of this ticket: [Wordpress Trac: Enchance `get_intermediate_image_sizes()` to contain not only the names, but the sizes too.](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18947)

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that this `global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;`
 might not work as expected. For example when using is in plugin it will not return the additional sizes that a Themes have registered.

Comment: It will if you make the call later enough in the action sequence, ie. if the theme registers the sizes on the init action, your call must be made after that action has occured.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is this function: **wp_get_attachment_image_src**

Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

It will return an array containing attachment's url, width and height.

Comment: Yes but it expects an ID for a given image, the user doesn't have an ID to pass, he wants to find out the registered size by name, eg. thumbnail(post_thumbnail).

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the post above:

```
$attachment = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id ); // where $attachment_id is the ID of the attachment you want to get the thumbnail from
```

Then simply use the next code to display the url, width and height:

```
echo $attachment[0]; // url
echo $attachment[1]; // width
echo $attachment[2]; // height
```