# Get custom thumbnail sizes

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

If I use:

```
add_image_size('main_image', 750, 375, true);
```

to add additional thumbnail size. Then how can i get that size if i have only key `main_image`.

Comment: Are you trying to get the *names* of the custom image sizes, or are you trying to return/output the actual *image* with the custom size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered here: [Get post thumbnail size](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36493/get-post-thumbnail-size)

```
global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
// Output width
echo $_wp_additional_image_sizes['main_image']['width'];
// Output height
echo $_wp_additional_image_sizes['main_image']['height'];
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the new image size in a theme you need to call to it with

`<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'main_image' ); } ?>`

If you need additional sizes just add more.

`add_image_size('main_image', 750, 375, true);`

`add_image_size('main_image_2', 650, 275, true);`

`add_image_size('main_image_3', 550, 175, true);`

You can learn how this function works here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`the_post_thumbnail()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) to *output* the featured image at the specified size:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'main_image' ); ?>
```

Use [**`get_the_post_thumbnail()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) to *return* the HTML image markup for the image at the specified size:

```
<?php get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'main_image' ); ?>
```